# How to check header status code for multiple pages in Behat?

Tags: php, unit-testing, behat, acceptance-testing

Lets say I have a few page slugs in the database which I would like to check with Behat if the pages are returning header status code 200.

This means I want to have one test(feature) which will check multiple pages, however I'm struggling in how to do this.

Right now I'm using something like this:

```
Given I am on any page, I should get header status code 200
```

Which starts one function and every logic is inside that function.

But ideally, I want something like this:

```
Given I go through all pages
When I check the header status for each page
Then I should get header status code 200
```

Is there a way to do this?

Note: I use a FeatureContext class and I tried storing e.g. all pages in a private variable, and then tried to access it in the next step of the feature, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a **single page**, it is done like this.

Example Scenario:

```
  Scenario: Request and Response for single page
    Given I am on "/homepage"
    When I send a GET request to "/cars/list_all"
    And the response status code should be 200
```

Example Context file:
You need to add method below.

```
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements KernelAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @When /^I send a ([^"]*) request to "([^"]*)"$/
     */
    public function iSendARequestTo($method, $url)
    {
        $client = $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getClient();
        $client->request($method, $url);
    }
}
```

MinkContext:
This already exists so you won't touch it.

```
class MinkContext extends RawMinkContext implements TranslatedContextInterface
{
    /**
     * Checks, that current page response status is equal to specified.
     *
     * @Then /^the response status code should be (?P<code>\d+)$/
     */
    public function assertResponseStatus($code)
    {
        $this->assertSession()->statusCodeEquals($code);
    }
}
```

---

For **multiple pages**, you'll use [Scenario Outlines](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/1.gherkin.html#scenario-outlines).

```
  Scenario Outline: Request and Response for multiple pages
    Given I am on "/homepage"
    When I send a <method> request to <end-point>
    And the response status code should be <response-code>

  Examples:
    | method | end-point     | response-code |
    | POST   | /api/page-one | 200           |
    | PUT    | /api/page-two | 200           |
```

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically supply the examples? For example, feed the results of a mysql query into the "end-point" parameters? Or supply an "end-point" argument on the command line?

Comment: I don't quiet get get it. It would be better if you could open up a question with more details and an dummy example.

Comment: OK, question posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026535/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-supply-variables-to-behat-features

Comment: Just seen. Writing an example at the moment. Should be there shortly.